# Cardinality of all rational points in $R^3$

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, cardinals

Question: Find the cardinality of the set of all points in $R^3$ all of whose coordinates are rational, and justify the answer.

Idea: Call the set of all points in $R^3$ all of whose coordinates are rational A. Also, I will make a set called B, that is the set of all coordinates (x,0,0) where x is any rational number. Now, from this it is clear that B has a cardinality of $\aleph_0$. Also It is clear that B is a subset of A. So cardinality of A is greater than or equal to cardinality of B. Therefore, cardinality of A is at least $\aleph_0$. I will then create a function $f$ that is injective from A to the set of all natural numbers. This function will be $f(x)= 2^{a_1}*3^{b_1}*5^{c_1}*7^{a_2}*11^{b_2}*13^{c_3}$ where $a_1$ is the integer in the numerator of a, $a_2$ is the integer in the denominator of a,where $b_1$ is the integer in the numerator of b, $b_2$ is the integer in the denominator of b,where $c_1$ is the integer in the numerator of c, $c_2$ is the integer in the denominator c, and a,b,c are any rational numbers.  Therefore, cardinality of A is less than or equal to $\aleph_0$. Therefore, cardinality of A is $\aleph_0$.

Question: would something like this work? Also, is there a way to do this by strictly using a bijection? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The function doesn't land in the natural numbers, because what if, for example, $a=1/2$?

Comment: shoot, for some reason i read that as integers. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: But you can still probably use that idea, you just have to use six primes and break up the rational to its numerator and denominator in lowest terms.  I think that may work.

Comment: If you already know $\vert\mathbb{Q}\vert=\aleph_0$, and know some basic cardinal arithmetic, you can just point out that $\vert A\vert=\aleph_0^3=\aleph_0$.

Comment: @Gregory Cant  It definitely got a lot worse to look at, but I think if phrased differently, something like that might work.

Comment: @Noah Scweber, that would work as well.

Comment: I see you edited your question to reflect the suggestion of using six primes.  One thing however, $12$ is not prime.

Comment: Do you know that there's a bijection $\Bbb N\to \Bbb Q$? and that there's a bijection $\Bbb N\times \Bbb N \to \Bbb N$ ?

Comment: @BrianO Yes we do know this.

Comment: Then you know that there are bijections $\Bbb N\to \Bbb N^2\to \Bbb N^3\to \Bbb Q^3$, so there you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map
$\mathbb{Q}^3
$
into
$N$
by
$(a/b, c/d, e/f)
\to
2^a3^b5^c7^d11^e13^f
$.

If you are worried about
the signs of the fractions,
use $3$ more primes to
handle those.

If you are worried about
$a, c, e$ being zero,
add one to them
after removing the sign.

Comment: What if one of those is negative?

Comment: As I said encode the signs into $(17,19,23)^{0,1}$.

Comment: Oh. I missed that part. Because it's not about "worrying" it's about having a well defined map. Negative powers of primes are rarely natural numbers again.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment for my reputation, I don't know if I should do this. But take care of the possibility of $a_1$ being negative. This would imply that for some x (in particular if x has some negative coordinate), f(x) would not even be integer.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with posting this as an answer since it does answer the question of "will this work", and You're right. . . It doesn't. Do you know if there is some function that would still work here?

Comment: That's true the image is not in $\mathbb Z$, but it is in $\mathbb Q$ which is good enough right?

Comment: @GregoryGrant I don't think so. I need the image in $N$, so that I can show this is denumerable, right?

Comment: @Matthew Thanks for approving me! For a hint for your question, think about a new "auxiliary" function that would take this integer numbers and transform them (inject them to be precise) into natural numbers. And then the next clue is to do a "composition".

Comment: @Matthew what gregory says is another way to end the exercise. There are always many ways. He says that we already know what cardinality the rationals have. But it can be done without it.

Comment: @Matthew You said "Now, from this it is clear that B has a cardinality of $\aleph_0$." where $B$ is basically $\Bbb Q$.  So I assumed you already know that $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb N$ have the same cardinality.

Comment: @Gregory Grant Oh! Yes, I was already aware of that. I just forgot by the time we got this far in the process. Thanks.